# How to become materialistic from spiritual?

Tags: spirituality

I know you may find it odd. But Hinduism is not spiritual or material based. So what should be done if a spiritual person wants to become materialistic. (Shankaracharya also went to a King's body to experience Gaarhasthya. I know we cannot relate this incidence here, nor can we compare ourselves to ShreeAdiShankaracharya, but still)

Comment: krishna says in BG that what we eat which may seem bad or taste bad but gives us good health is satvik on the other hand what may taste good but effect health is Rajsik , so if you start enjoying Rajsik things you may be sticking to material again , they layer of maya is also created by God himself so its on you to decide whether you want to get bound by it or not

Comment: @Friendy I think we can live spiritually even when we are enjoying worldly pleasures

Comment: And I think Bhakti is what is needed?

Comment: See the Gita chapters 14 and 16, especially 16.

Comment: Actually you have given yourself a certificate of spiritual being which is delusional. You're already material, just assuming you're spiritual like everyone including myself.

Comment: @RohitSinghRathore you are quite right, that I am materialistic. But my question is- like there are ways of becoming spiritual, so there might also be ways of becoming materialistic.

Comment: Why are people downvoting this question?

Comment: @SreeCharan this shows how great you are. People act like a sheep of flock. They are thinking this question 'offends' Hinduism or Spirituality.

Comment: Take to capitalistic countries to learn the way of capitalism, hang out and make friends with capitalists. Get a business education! Boris Yeltsin the leader of Russia back in the days disliked the capitalists/imperialists, but once made diplomatic visit to USA and went to a supermarket, when he saw the abundance of the supermarket he realized that planned economy wasn't the way and was way inferior to capitalism, so "seeing is believing".

Comment: At home russians had to stand hour long queues to get a few lousy scraps of meat, even big factories had their own cows they could milk, because the infrastructure was so bad!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very simple - just think about material things.

[Krishna says in Gita (2.62-63)](https://asitis.com/2/62.html):

> dhyayato visayan pumsah
> sangas tesupajayate
> sangat sanjayate kamah
> kamat krodho 'bhijayate
>
> While contemplating the objects of the senses, a person develops attachment for them, and from such attachment lust develops, and from lust anger arises.
>
> krodhad bhavati sammohah
> sammohat smrti-vibhramah
> smrti-bhramsad buddhi-naso
> buddhi-nasat pranasyati
>
> From anger, delusion arises, and from delusion bewilderment of memory. When memory is bewildered, intelligence is lost, and when intelligence is lost, one falls down again into the material pool.

From thinking about stuff, association is born. From association, desire. From desire, anger (when desire is not fulfilled). Anger -> Illusion -> Memory bewildered (as to what is right or wrong) -> Intelligence lost -> Nasham (destruction).

All you need to do is mentally keep thinking about material things (food, money, power, women, prestige) and associating with materialistic people, and you'll automatically develop desire and attachment towards those.

Answer (score 2):

> Spirituality is ego-less condition of our being. In, non dual terms, indwelling is our real nature is spirituality.

After defining spirituality as above in non dual terms, I would like to attempt to answer how to become spiritual, not following which, one can be material. As darkness is nothing but absence of light.
So, To become material one has to objectify the self only.
One can objectify the self by going against these verses said by Adi Shankar (Atma Shatakam)-

> I have no hatred or dislike, nor affiliation or liking, nor greed, nor delusion, nor pride or haughtiness, nor feelings of envy or jealousy. I have no duty (dharma), nor any money, nor any desire (kāma), nor even liberation (mokṣa). I am indeed, That eternal knowing and bliss, the auspicious (Śivam), love and pure consciousness. (Verse 3)

See, you can easily become material (though you/we already are) by converting **real I** into **psycho-phyical I** or removing not/nor in the verses.

Same procedure you can apply in other verses as well.

> I have neither merit (virtue), nor demerit (vice). I do not commit sins or good deeds, nor have happiness or sorrow, pain or pleasure. I do not need mantras, holy places, scriptures (Vedas), rituals or sacrifices (yajñas). I am none of the triad of the observer or one who experiences, the process of observing or experiencing, or any object being observed or experienced. I am indeed, That eternal knowing and bliss, the auspicious (Śivam), love and pure consciousness. ( verse 4)
>
> I do not have fear of death, as I do not have death. I have no separation from my true self, no doubt about my existence, nor have I discrimination on the basis of birth. I have no father or mother, nor did I have a birth. I am not the relative, nor the friend, nor the guru, nor the disciple. I am indeed, That eternal knowing and bliss, the auspicious (Śivam), love and pure consciousness. (Verse 5)
>
> I am all pervasive. I am without any attributes, and without any form. I have neither attachment to the world, nor to liberation (mukti). I have no wishes for anything because I am everything, everywhere, every time, always in equilibrium. I am indeed, That eternal knowing and bliss, the auspicious (Śivam), love and pure consciousness. (Verse 6)

**So, in actual we are already material as we identify ourselves as something which we're not. Our basic 'I' is ontologically psycho-phyical already rather than real 'I' therefore we don't need to put extra efforts to become material anymore.**